# format a Date column in a Data Frame

Tags: r

I've the following data from a data frame

```
Name,JoiningDate,AmtPaid
Joe,12/31/09,1000
Amy,10/28/09,100
John,05/06/10,200
```

The Joining Date is coming in as a factor (when I `sapply`). How can I convert this to date and then sort on `JoiningDate`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This should do it (where df is your dataframe)

```
df$JoiningDate <- as.Date(df$JoiningDate , format = "%m/%d/%y")

df[order(df$JoiningDate ),]
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. How it is possible that `mode(as.Date(df$JoiningDate, "%m/%d/%Y"))` returns `numeric` ?

Comment: @ Lao Tzu you should open up a new question, your query may not get seen here. I believe that internally, dates are stored as numeric seconds since the start of Unix time (1st January 1970). Hope this helps.

Comment: When I do this, it's turning my column into NAs

Comment: @TravisHeeter try this package, most likely your date is in a different format than what `as.Date` understands https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/anytime.pdf

Comment: I get same issue as @TravisHeeter, date column become `NA`s.

Answer (score 6):

try this package, works wonders, and was made for date/time...

```
library(lubridate)
Portfolio$Date2 <- mdy(Portfolio.all$Date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` package has its `IDate` class and functionalities similar to `lubridate` or the `zoo` package. You could do:

```r
dt = data.table(
  Name = c('Joe', 'Amy', 'John'),
  JoiningDate = c('12/31/09', '10/28/09', '05/06/10'),
  AmtPaid = c(1000, 100, 200)
)

require(data.table)
dt[ , JoiningDate := as.IDate(JoiningDate, '%m/%d/%y') ]
```